# Question about STATA RDROBUST command usage (Regression Discontinuity Design)

Tags: regression-discontinuity

I am using the Stata rdrobust command for RDD analysis, aiming to perform a two-stage analysis. The first stage is to model the probability of receiving the treatment at cut-off and the second stage is to use the predicted value of the treatment variable on my dependent variables. I am taking a log of the forcing variable to remove skewness in the distribution. I have tried two kinds of argument specifications in the rdrobust command.

Assume cut-off value is "C", "X" is forcing variable, "T" is treatment, "Y" is my dependent variable. I do not explicitly specify bandwidth and the command uses an optimal data-driven bandwidth selection algorithm. Regression fit is local linear polynomial.

**Specification 1**: I calculate cut_off_margin = log(X) - log(C) (i.e. distance between forcing variable and cut-off in terms of log difference). Here, command uses zero cut-off.

**command:**
rdrobust Y cut_off_margin, fuzzy(T) p(1) c(0)

**Specification 2:** In this specification, the forcing variable and cut-off "C" is directly passed onto the command, which works fine.

**command:**
rdrobust Y X, fuzzy(T) p(1) c(C)

There is some difference in output between specification 1 and 2. Is there any suggestions about which specification is more precise while using this STATA command?